# Is there anyway to detect a variant change in Shopify using an external Javascript/jquery file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I have written an external JS script that shows a custom text on the stores product's page. Currently the JS function is called once, on the window.onload function.

I want my script to be able to detect a variant change and swap out the text to a different one, whenever a different variant is selected. How do I detect a variant change and get it's price in an external JS file, using only JS/jQuery function.

```
<script id="testscript" src="https://example.com/test.js?amount=${{ product.price | divided_by: 100.00 | round: 2 }}"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>

My code in test.js:
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += ("<p>This is a test.</p>");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your theme structure looks like. Let's assume you are using Debut theme:
https://debut-demo.myshopify.com/products/laptop-sleeve

You need to set an event listener on the element of your page that's responsible for variant change. On the page above it's a select that allows customers to change item size.

If you open page inspector and preview website code, select element has the following structure:

```
<select class="single-option-selector single-option-selector-product-template product-form__input" id="SingleOptionSelector-0" data-index="option1">                    
    <option value="13”" selected="selected">13”</option>
    <option value="15”">15”</option>
</select>
```

You can achieve it in to ways. First step is to create such function in your JS file:

```
function detectChange(element) {
    var value = element.value;
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    myDiv.innerHTML += `<p>${value}</p>`;
}
```

Then either add the function as event listener in `select` element:

```
<select class="single-option-selector single-option-selector-product-template product-form__input" id="SingleOptionSelector-0" data-index="option1" onchange="detectChange(this)">
```

OR bind the listener to an element:

```
document.getElementById("SingleOptionSelector-0").addEventListener("change", detectChange(this));
```